# How fix window on top

Tags: winapi, setforegroundwindow

I use `SetForegroundWindow` to set window of other application on the top. How I can fix this window on the top? It means, once some other application calls `SetForegroundWindow`, my window will be below my fixed window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make your window top-most by setting the `WS_EX_TOPMOST` extended style when you create the window, or afterwards by calling `SetWindowPos` with `HWND_TOPMOST` as the second parameter.

Note however there's no way to make your window stay on top of other top-most windows (i.e. there's no "on top of absolutely everything" flag).

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to make sure your window is always on top:

1. Constantly check in a loop if your window is still TOPMOST and set it TOPMOST if not:

   `if (::GetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_EXSTYLE) & WS_EX_TOPMOST)
   {
      // restore topmost
   }`
2. Set a system wide hook for Z-order change via `SetWindowsHookEx(WH_CBT or WH_CALLWNDPROC)` , and then take appropriate action when your window gets under another.